# Jquery mobile datebox

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, datebox

I'm using jquery-mobile datebox plugin, namely slidebox mode. The problems is that i need to select only a range of minutes (0-15, 15-30, 30-45, 45-60). Is it possible to somehow change the default minutes range to given above?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @SivaCharan http://mobiscroll.com/

Comment: Rather than giving a link to another site. Edit your question and place your HTML and Jquery snippets.

Comment: @SivaCharan i posted question at Aug 28 at 5:55 and you think after a month i still need answers?

Comment: If you resolved the answer, better post it as answer. So it will helpful to others.